# System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'MobileAuthenticatedStream' in xamarin forms

Tags: exception, xamarin.forms, mobile, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am creating a project in xamarin forms android and ios. I am getting this error in app center,

MobileAuthenticatedStream.StartOperation (Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream+OperationType type, Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs, line 410
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'MobileAuthenticatedStream'.

How to resolve this error in xamarin forms android and ios

Comment: Hey..you got any solution for this?